# Libre Calc: Creating Formula to Add Rows (D thru I) to Another Row (J)

Tags: libreoffice

LibreCalc: Help Creating a Formula to Add Rows ( under D thru I) to Another Row under(J)and would like to have descending Rows do the same thing with different input data. 
Say Row 2 (D to I) has a set of numbers that I need to show the total in Row 2 under J Column.
Then Row 3 (D to I) will have different data that needs to total in J-3....what I'm looking for is how to set this up so each following Row entry will auto total to J on a constant basis without having to manually enter each Rows values to obtain the J value.

Comment: Show us an example of the sheet and the formulas you've tried which did not work right.

Comment: If you want to copy a formula into multiple cells, there is a quick and easy way to copy into adjacent cell areas:

Select the cell containing the formula.
Position the mouse on the bottom right of the highlighted border of the cell, and continue holding down the mouse button until the pointer changes to a cross-hair symbol.
With the mouse button pressed, drag it down or to the right over all the cells into which you want to copy the formula.
When you release the mouse button, the formula will be copied into the cells and automatically adjusted.

Comment: a friend passed this along to me and it was exactly what I needed to do what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy a formula into multiple cells, there is a quick and easy way to copy into adjacent cell areas:

Select the cell containing the formula.
Position the mouse on the bottom right of the highlighted border of the cell, and continue holding down the mouse button until the pointer changes to a cross-hair symbol.
With the mouse button pressed, drag it down or to the right over all the cells into which you want to copy the formula.
When you release the mouse button, the formula will be copied into the cells and automatically adjusted.